# TFlite and Android Studio - Inference with float model

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to deploy a non-quantized TFlite model (data type is float32) to android studio, but I don't know how to define de bytebuffer for inference. When I load the model in Android Studio I obtain the following suggestions:

```
val model = Model.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 256, 256, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

However, bytebuffer is not defined and I do not how to do so. For the moment I have only seen people define it straightforward for Int8 models.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this help https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference